# Upload Image to Blob using GAE + Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, image-uploading

I'm writing an application using GAE and Django in which I want to give to user the ability to upload his image. Also, I want this image be stored as blob on GAE's datastore. I have seen many examples but nothing specific to this scenario. Although, I feel that is a common issue.

All I want, is to create a new product and this new product must have an image.

**1st Attempt:** I have tried to add an image attribute (db.BlobProperty()) in product's model, and obviously django does not include it on the presented form.

**2nd Attempt:** I have created a new entity with two attributes (product as db.ReferenceProperty() and image as db.BlobProperty()). With this I tried to work parallel with django form modifying the django HTML form (including an |input type='file' name='img' /|) expecting that I could take the image from the request object but I failed once more.

This is the Product Class:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.IntegerProperty()
    desc = db.StringProperty()
    prodCateg = db.ReferenceProperty(ProductCategory)
    price = db.FloatProperty()
    details = db.StringProperty()
    image = db.BlobProperty()
```

This is the Django Form (HTML):

```
<form action="{%url admin.editProduct product.key.id%}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table>
{{form}}
<tr><td><input type="file" name="img" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Create or Edit Product"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the Django Form (python):

```
class ProductForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Product
    exclude = ['id']
```

This is the request handler:

```
def editProduct(request, product_id):
  user = users.GetCurrentUser()
  #if user is None:
  #  return http.HttpResponseForbidden('You must be signed in to add or edit a gift')

  product = None
  if product_id:
    product = Product.get(db.Key.from_path(Product.kind(), int(product_id)))
    if product is None:
      return http.HttpResponseNotFound('No product exists with that key (%r)' %
                                       product)

  form = ProductForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=product)

  ##########################
  # Ambitious undertaking! #
  ##########################
  #if not product_id:
  #    uploadedImage = get("img")
  #    photo = Image()
  #    photo.product = product
  #    uploadedPhoto = request.FILES['img'].read()
  #    photo.image = db.Blob(uploadedPhoto)
  #    image.put()

  if not request.POST:
    return respond(request, user, 'addprod', {'form': form, 'product': product})

  errors = form.errors
  if not errors:
    try:
      product = form.save(commit=False)
    except ValueError, err:
      errors['__all__'] = unicode(err)
  if errors:
    return respond(request, user, 'addprod', {'form': form, 'product': product})

  product.put()

  return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/product')
```

As you can see the request handler is based on the Google's Gift-Tutorial

So, If anyone could put his opinion I would be very thankful!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at an example that uses the [blobstore API with blobstoreuploadhandler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers.html) and/or edit your request handler to store the uploaded file as a blobproperty or a blobreferenceproperty depending on if you use the blobstore API or just a blobproperty variable. You can be specific about http post data i.e. `

`self.request.post('img').file.read()`
I do recommend that you choose the blobstore API and blobstoreuploadhandler since that will do some very good things for you automatically: 1. storing MIM type and 2. storing filename 3. enabling serving via get_serving_url that has several advantages.